# Can't POST a request to service

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

For some reason I always get `Endpoint not found.`, but when I put it in the browser it works perfectly. I'm sure doing something wrong..

```
- (void)requestLoad:(NSString *)req_udid Age:(NSString *)req_age Gender:(NSString *)req_gender CheckBoxes:(NSString *)req_checkBoxes
{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/UpdatePersonalInterests/%@/%@/%@/%@/0",req_udid, req_age, req_gender, req_checkBoxes];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    //set up the request to the website
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"kServiceURL", @"urls", nil)]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",result);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get endpoint not found?

Comment: In here:     `NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

    `NSLog(@"%@",result);`

Comment: have you tried to just put it in the web browsers address field, or have you tried to POST to the same url? maybe that endpoint is just set up to receive GET requests

Comment: Not really following your question. Are you saying NSLog prints out "Endpoint not found"? Or is this something you see in some other error on the console.

Comment: the NSLog printing the `result` that is: `Endpoint not found.` - the result should be `"Operation Succeed"` or `"Operation Failed"`.

Comment: Did you log error or response to see if they contain any information?

Comment: It looks like you are using a service scheme. Did you register the service scheme in Target -> info - URLS Types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to do this with NSURLConnection and asynchronous request with this code:

```
- (void)getIntrests
{
    NSString *req_udid = [PROUtils createOrLoadUserIdentifier];
    NSString *webaddress = [kServiceBaseURL stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/GetPersonalInterestsForUdid/%@",req_udid]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webaddress] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error) {
         NSString* dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kGotMediaFromServer object:dataString];

         NSLog(@"Update response completed: %@ with data: %@ error: %@",response,dataString,error);
     }];
}
```

Hope that it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a Custom Service scheme. Did you register it in Target -> info - URLS Types? See the Apple Docs or Registering custom URL Schemes: [Implementing Custom URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

Comment: Why do I need to register it?